# jQuery Validate submitHandler not displaying response

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a jQuery validation script that is working perfectly with the except of the event handler. I have simplified this post for troubleshooting purposes.

**jQuery**

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: $(form).attr("method"),
                    url: $(form).attr("action"),
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    dataType : "json"
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    if (data.resp > 0 ) {
                        alert(data.message);                       
                    }
                });
                return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
            },
 // rest of the validation below, truncated for clarity
```

The submitHandler successfully posts to my PHP script that adds a user to a database and then echoes back a json_encode() result.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    // All processing code above this line has been truncated for brevity

    if($rows == "1"){
        $resp = array("resp"=>1, "message"=>"Account created successfully. Waiting for user activation.");
    }else{
        $resp = array("resp"=>2, "message"=>"User account already exists.");
    }

    echo json_encode($resp);
?>
```

As you can see the idea is simple. Alert the user with the proper response message. When I run my script the user account is added successfully to the database but no alert is displayed to the user. The Console in Chrome shows no errors, what am I missing?

Comment: console log the data and see what you're getting back.

Comment: {resp: "Account Created Successfully."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering I was able to get things working the way I wanted. Here's the updated code.

**jQuery**

```
.done(function (data) {
$("#user_add_dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    close: function (event, ui) {
    },
    title: "Add User",
    resizable: false,
    width: 500,
    height: "auto"
});
$("#user_add_dialog").html(data.message);
$("#user_add_dialog").dialog("open");
});

return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    // All processing code above this line has been truncated for brevity

    if($rows == "1"){
        $resp = array("message"=>"Account created successfully. Waiting for user activation.");
    }else{
        $resp = array("message"=>"User account already exists.");
    }

    echo json_encode($resp);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data` variable in the done() is a string. You have to transform it to an object like this

```
var response = $.parseJSON(data);
```

in order to access the attributes

Comment: This generated an "unrecognized token" in the JavaScript Console in Chrome and no alert window popped up. Expanding out the alert in the console reveals that it throws an "anonymous function" error on the var declaration.

Comment: I added a console.log(data) statement to verify I was getting JSON passed back and I am: {resp: "Account Created Successfully."}

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I missed `dataType : "json"` in your code in my previous answer.
Any way I tried your code and it is working. The `alert` shows the message. I think you have an error somewhere else. I think it has some thing to do with the array you are encoding to json(PHP part). The response you get is not complete. Try to debug your PHP and test the page separately from AJAX and see what is the result

Comment: If I put simply alert(data) in my function the alert pops up but instead of the message text it says [object Object]